# Using PHash (OpenCV) in Java

Tags: java, opencv, phash

I use the org.openpnp:opencv:4.5.1-2 library to integrate OpenCV with a server backend but somehow I miss the pHash function / implementation.

Did anyone have managed to get the OpenCV pHash version working in Java?

Comment: The module `img_hash` is part of [contrib](https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib/tree/master/modules/img_hash). That package probably wasn't built with any of the contrib stuff (fairly common occurrence).

Comment: That explains it. Is there any Java wrapper for this package?

Comment: No idea, I rarely use Java. You might just want to build your own binaries with just the modules you need enabled to keep the size reasonable.